# Windows uninstallation needs to run command under every user

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a program that installs a WSL distro to every user in the machine. The WSL distro installation is done by the program when each user first starts the app. However, at uninstall time, the WSL context is only related to the user running the uninstallation meaning that every other user remains with their distro installed. Is there a way run a command for every user in the machine? Specifically I need to run: wsl --unregister .

I understand there is the runas option, but according to my understanding one needs to know the credentials of the user that way.

I have already considered deleting the ext4.vhdx files and removing the WSL registry entries. But, I would rather stick to the "wsl" API, given that who knows if their implementation internals would ever change.

Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You can remove WSL at the system level with `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName 'Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux' | Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature` in windows 10/11. Depending on how you installed the distro originally, you may still have to clean up the user vhdx files. Some other suggestions here: https://superuser.com/questions/1317883/completely-uninstall-the-subsystem-for-linux-on-win10

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not what I want to do. There is the scenario where the user actually wants to use WSL for other purposes so I can't just uninstall it.

Comment: Assuming you just loaded that distro .appx package for the user, try `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | FL Name,PackageUserInformation` as administrator, and see if it got registered here as a package (add `-Name 'MyDistro'` if you know the exact name). Then you can uninstall with `Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`. Otherwise, show what your program does?

Comment: Thanks @Cpt.Whale, however, the distro is installed using wsl --import and it seems due to that, it doesn't show with that command. Then again, I could wrap the distro with an installer and then that would show up right?